# Flutter weird bug with widget function, sometimes in runs 2 times instead of one

Tags: flutter

This function have futureBuilder inside and returns another function that returns ListView.

Also I do not want the user to download information from the Internet every time they visit the page, so I put the information downloaded from the Internet into a static variable in class, so i make if else. If this static variable length != 0 , it return me listView instead of make server request with futureBuilder

function that works 2 times instead of one is ListView body

And also this bug created after i added purchases to my application, maybe something wrong there. I don't have any ideas  why this happend

this is my complete code

```
    class AddCheckList extends StatefulWidget {
      const AddCheckList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _AddCheckListState createState() => _AddCheckListState();

}
class _AddCheckListState extends State<AddCheckList> {
  String xQueryReqestForCheckListNames = "element CheckListList {for \$a in PACK/OBJECT where (\$a/@inUse = 'True') order by \$a/@name return element CheckList {attribute name {\$a/@name}, attribute sPaid {\$a/@isPaid},attribute oid {\$a/@oid} }}";
  String serverLink = "http...";
  int addCheckListMethod = 0;
  // if addCheckListMethod == 0, then data will download from server and checkLists will be added from server xml data
  // if addCheckListMethod == 1, then data will download from assets, and checkLists will be added from assets xml data with getXmlData function
  final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;
  final String _productID = '1d7ea644f690ffa';

  bool _available = true;
  List<ProductDetails> _products = [];
  List<PurchaseDetails> _purchases = [];
  StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>>? _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated = _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;

    _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
      setState(() {
        _purchases.addAll(purchaseDetailsList);
        _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
      });
    }, onDone: () {
      _subscription!.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      _subscription!.cancel();
    });

    _initialize();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription!.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _initialize() async {
    _available = await _inAppPurchase.isAvailable();

    List<ProductDetails> products = await _getProducts(
      productIds: Set<String>.from(
        [_productID],
      ),
    );

    setState(() {
      _products = products;
    });
  }

  void _listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
    purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
      switch (purchaseDetails.status) {
        case PurchaseStatus.pending:
          //  _showPendingUI();
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.purchased:
        case PurchaseStatus.restored:
          // bool valid = await _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
          // if (!valid) {
          //   _handleInvalidPurchase(purchaseDetails);
          // }
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.error:
          print(purchaseDetails.error!);
          // _handleError(purchaseDetails.error!);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

      if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
        await _inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<List<ProductDetails>> _getProducts({required Set<String> productIds}) async {
    ProductDetailsResponse response = await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(productIds);

    return response.productDetails;
  }

  void _subscribe({required ProductDetails product}) {
    final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: product);
    _inAppPurchase.buyNonConsumable(
      purchaseParam: purchaseParam,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.0), child: listViweBody(addCheckListMethod, serverLink, xQueryReqestForCheckListNames, _products,_subscribe)),
    );
  }
}


Widget listView(addCheckListMethod, serverLink, product,_subscribe) {
  return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: CheckListModel.checkListModelNamesFromServer.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (CheckListModel.checkListModelNamesFromServer[index].ispaid == false) {
          return InkWell(
            onTap: () async {
              CheckListModel checkList = CheckListModel('', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, '', [], '');
              if (addCheckListMethod == 0) {
                String xQueryReqestForCheckList = 'for \$a in PACK/OBJECT where \$a/@name="${CheckListModel.checkListModelNamesFromServer[index].name}" return \$a';
                var data = await CheckListModel.getDataFromServer(xQueryReqestForCheckList, serverLink);

                CheckListModel.addCheckListFromServer(checkList, data);
              } else {
                CheckListModel.addCheckList(index, checkList);
              }
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: Text("Добавить описание"),
                      content: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Color.fromARGB(Desing.colorFromARGBBtn[0], Desing.colorFromARGBBtn[1], Desing.colorFromARGBBtn[2], Desing.colorFromARGBBtn[3]), width: 1), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Описание", border: InputBorder.none),
                          maxLines: null,
                          onChanged: (String value) async {
                            checkList.description = value;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      actions: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Text("Отменить"),
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await checkList.writeToFile(checkList.toJson());
                              CheckListModel.checkLists.add(checkList);
                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/beforeMainCheckList', arguments: {'index': CheckListModel.checkLists.length - 1});
                            },
                            child: Text('Добавить'))
                      ],
                    );
                  });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Color.fromARGB(Desing.colorFromARGBBtn[0], Desing.colorFromARGBBtn[1], Desing.colorFromARGBBtn[2], Desing.colorFromARGBBtn[3]), width: 1), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              width: 50,
              height: 80,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "${CheckListModel.checkListModelNamesFromServer[index].name}",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          if (product.length != 0) {
            return showPurchaseCheckLists(product, index,_subscribe);
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        }
      },
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          height: 14,
        );
      });
}
Widget showPurchaseCheckLists(product, index,_subscribe) {
  int getCurrentProduct() {
    String? checkListModelid = CheckListModel.checkListModelNamesFromServer[index].checkListId?.toLowerCase();
    int indexx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
      if (checkListModelid == product[i].id) {
        indexx = i;
      }
    }
    return indexx;
  }

  return InkWell(
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Color.fromARGB(Desing.colorFromARGBBtn[0], Desing.colorFromARGBBtn[1], Desing.colorFromARGBBtn[2], Desing.colorFromARGBBtn[3]), width: 1), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), color: Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 240, 240)),
      width: 50,
      height: 80,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            "${CheckListModel.checkListModelNamesFromServer[index].name}",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
          ),
          Text("Купить за ${product[getCurrentProduct()].price}")
        ],
      ),
    ),
    onTap: () {
      _subscribe(product: product[getCurrentProduct()]);
    },
  );
}

Widget listViweBody(addCheckListMethod, serverLink, xQueryReqestForCheckListNames, product,_subscribe) {
  if (CheckListModel.checkListModelNamesFromServer.length == 0) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: CheckListModel.getDataFromServer(xQueryReqestForCheckListNames, serverLink),
        builder: (context, data) {
          if (data.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return listView(addCheckListMethod, serverLink, product,_subscribe);
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        });
  } else {
    return listView(addCheckListMethod, serverLink, product,_subscribe);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use any sort of state management for your shop? This might be a better approach for your shop. You call the API once, and you store the data received in your class on you app start or when you open a specific page, and you make a CRUD model where you update your state and UI when you do an action, so in my honest opinion, you don't need to use a Stream builder at all. Try reading a bit about [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

Comment: And I'm not 100% sure, but it seems your bug might be that when you do an action/update the UI, it builds it self multiple times. Also, in `_listenToPurchaseUpdated` method, after  `case PurchaseStatus.purchased:` you need `break;`.

Comment: @GrandMagus this is first time add purchases to application, this more like tests right now, thanks for advice

Comment: @GrandMagus CheckListModel.checkListModelNamesFromServer.length == 8 , so UI build correctly depend on data that it have, i will check is it problem with server, server send me correct data